# Can someone explain why this coordinate math works?

Tags: java, math, coordinates

Visual a canvas with square spaces that an object can move along in the x and y directions, but not diagonal.  Movement is based on mouse coordinates captured from a mouse click (mouseX, mouseY).  Assume obj.move() moves from its relative location to the provided (x,y) location.

```
if (Math.abs(mouseX-objX) > Math.abs(mouseY-objY)){
    if(mouseX > objX){
        obj.move(SQUARE_SIZE, 0);
    }else{
        obj.move(-SQUARE_SIZE, 0);
    }
}else{
    if(mouseY > objY){
        obj.move(0, SQUARE_SIZE);
    }else{
        obj.move(0, -SQUARE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

I understand all the code, but I cannot grasp the mathematical concept.  Can someone explain this graphically or point me somewhere on the right path?

Not important right now (until I understand this math), but if I wanted to include diagonal movement into this, how would I go about it?

Comment: Not important part -> You would provide a value in place of `0` in the move calls.

Comment: It's not really math concept, except in very general sense of all programming being math. You have 4 possible actions, and have two levels of if-else to reach the right one. Try it with grid paper, put object there, then do "mouse clicks" and see which branch is executed.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Yes, but what under what condition would I provide that value?

Comment: @hyde, I have done that.  I just can't seem to wrap my head around why it works.  Why is it getting absolute values?  Maybe I'm just stupid.

Comment: When the current click location has changes in both directions. IOW when the click occurs you could find dx and dy.

Comment: @patterned It uses absolute values because it wants to calculate the distance from the click to the object, which can be both negative or positive depending on where you click. Now to compare the two distances it's easiest to just compare the absolute values of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with directions you need both a distance and a direction. For example if `dX = -2`, the distance is `|dX| = 2` and the direction is `sign(dX) = -1`. You can simplify your code by using these terms.

```
int dx = mouseX - objX, distX = Math.abs(dX), dirX = Math.signum(dX);
int dy = mouseY - objY, distY = Math.abs(dY), dirY = Math.signum(dY);

// Move diagonal
if(distX == distY))
    obj.move(dirX * SQUARE_SIZE, dirY * SQUARE_SIZE);

// Move horizontal
else if(distX > distY)
    obj.move(dirX * SQUARE_SIZE, 0);

// Move vertical
else
    obj.move(0, dirY * SQUARE_SIZE);
```

### Examples:

Lets say you start at position 0 (green) and the mouse is clicked at position 3 (red):

**Example 1** (no diagonal):

[image]

1. (from pos:0) `dX = 2, dy = -1`, so `|dX| > |dy|`, and `dirX > 0`, move right (`SQUARE_SIZE`)
2. (from pos:1) `dX = 1, dy = -1`, so `|dX|<= |dy|`, and `dirY < 0`, move down (`-SQUARE_SIZE`)
3. (from pos:2) `dX = 1, dy = 0`, so `|dX| > |dy|`, and `dirX > 0`, move right (`SQUARE_SIZE`)
4. (from pos:3) Done

**Example 2** (with diagonal):

[image]

1. (from pos:0) `dX = 2, dy = -1`, so `|dX| > |dy|`, and `dirX > 0`, move right (`SQUARE_SIZE`)
2. (from pos:1) `dX = 1, dy = -1`, so `|dX| = |dy|`, and `dirX > 0` and `dirY < 0`, (`SQUARE_SIZE`, `-SQUARE_SIZE`)
3. (from pos:2) Done

Comment: You seemed to have spent the most time, and the simple graph helped me visualize it.  Any chance you could show/explain code to move diagonal?

Comment: @patterned okay, I've added the diagonal to the codde at the top. Essentially, you would move diagonal if |dX| = |dy|

Comment: Very comprehensive. +1

Comment: @bcorso This all makes sense, the only problem is here:

    if(distX == distY))

I can't get this to work correctly.  Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't your mouse have to be at exactly a 45 degree angle (e.g. obj is 75,75 mouse would have to be (+ or -)75+n,(+ or -)75+n )??

Comment: @patterned not exactly, it just means that it will travel vertically or horizontally until dX = dY. In example 2, it first moves right, and then dX = dY so it moves vertically.

Comment: so if obj is at (0, 0) and mouse click was at (76, 75), then obj would first travel horizontally one space, and then diagonally: (0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 2) -> ... -> (76, 75).

Comment: @bcorso Can you help me walk through this?  Say SQUARE_SIZE = 100.  I draw my object on the canvas where the center point is (+50,+50). Say I click (+100,+100).  dx = 50, dy = 50 so |dX| == |dY|.  But if I click (+100,+80) dx = 50, dy = 30 so |dx| > |dY|.  (+100,+80) is within the bounds of that square but it will still move right.  [here is a visual](http://i.imgur.com/IpFXjzB.png).

Comment: If the user can pick any pixel in the SQUARE_SIZE, you will have to convert the mouse position to a cell. For example: clicking (100,100) should correspond to cell (1,1) and (100,80) should correspond to cell (1, 0). However, this is a little different than how you initially described your problem. If you need more help you should post another question with the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

It just checks if the offset of the mouse from the object into the x direction is larger than into the y.

If it is larger, it will move into the x direction, the actual direction depending on whether the mouse is to the left or right of the current object.

If it is smaller, it will move into the y direction, again the actual direction depending on whether the mouse is above or below the current object.